# Java file executing using ActiveXObject only works when placing in Desktop

Tags: java, activex, activexobject

I have an application which based on `java` and I am making use of `ActiveXObject` to call it.

I have referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608356/how-to-use-wscript-exec-to-run-a-java-file) and it helped.

I have called my java class file as follows:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("cmd  /c java Test \""+param+"\"");
```

**It works when I put my class file Test in Desktop.**

I have placed my java file inside `C:/Myapp` folder

So I make neccessary changes in javascript activexobject call as follows:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("cmd  /c java C:/Myapp/Test \""+param+"\"");
```

It is not working.

For testing purpose I tried the command without `/c`. In both cases CMD is appearing with path upto Desktop.

How can I execute the java file while placing inside  `C:/Myapp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use CLASSPATH switch, and you can test it in command prompt first.

use `shell.run("cmd  /c java -cp C:\\Myapp Test \""+param+"\"");` to mention the base location of the class files.

Comment: You mean `shell.run("cmd  /c java -cp C:\\Myapp Test  \""+param+"\"");` right?

Comment: @Santhucool onmore thing `C:\Myapp` should have the compiled class file not the Java source file.

Comment: I have tried as per you mentioned but still not working. Yah it is having Test.java,Test.class file

Comment: What is the out put when you run the follwing from cmd prompt? `java -cp C:\Myapp Test`

Comment: It was a messup. I got it. Thanks a lot buddy